# How to mock a logger for unit testing in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing

The method that i need to unit test logs the output in the following way and doesnt return anything. How do i write a unit test method for the following case? Please help i'm new to this concept and havent written any test methods before

```
private void revoke (params) {
    if (userexist (revokedb, userid))``
{
        deleteusers (revokedb, userid);
        if (userexist (revokedb, userid))
       {
           logger.info ("Not able to delete user");
       }
       else
       {
          logger.info ("User was succesfully deleted");
       }
    else
  {
       logger.info ("unable of find the user");
  }
}
```

Comment: What logger? Where does it come from? It matters. .NET's ILogger has a NullLogger class for testing purposes, so you'd have to change the code that calls the class's constructor and pass a `NullLogger` to it.

Comment: As above; how are you creating the logger, is it being injected, `logger.info` isn't the Logging ILogger interface so what are you using etc

Answer (score 1):

I think you can inject the logger in the class constructor like below.

```
public class BusService : IBusService
    {
        private readonly ILogger _logger;
        public BusService(ILogger<BusService> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }
        private void revoke (params) {
    if (userexist (revokedb, userid))``
    {
        deleteusers (revokedb, userid);
        if (userexist (revokedb, userid))
       {
           _logger.info ("Not able to delete user");
       }
       else
       {
          _logger.info ("User was successfully deleted");
       }
    else
    {
       _logger.info ("unable of find the user");
    }
  }
}
```

Once it is injected in class constructor like above, you can use Moq class to mock your logger like below test method.

```
[Fact]
public void BusService_revoke_deleteUser()
        {
            // Arrange
            var logger = Mock.Of<ILogger<BusService>>();
            
            var busService = new BusService(logger);
            
            // Act
            var result = busService.revoke(params);

            // Assert
             // Assert statement will go here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out `moq` https://github.com/Moq/moq4

your logger needs to implement an interface that you can then mock.

E.g.

`MyLogger:ILogger`

`ILogger` would define the method `info(string)`

in your test, you'd set up your mock first

```
var mock = new Mock<ILoveThisLibrary>();
```

and then you can inject this mock into your class (where `logger`) is used. Either through the constructir or any other method that replaces the actual logger with this mock object. This is called dependency injection.

Now all calls to `logger` will get directed to your mock object and you can do all sorts of mocking. E.g. expectations, i.e. checking that `info` was called with the string that you expect.

Comment: Also worth checking out NSubstitute - https://nsubstitute.github.io/. I used Moq for years and much prefer NSubstitute. IMO it's even simpler